# PHP/JQuery Dynamic Drop Down not sending variable via POST

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a two step drop down menu. The second select is triggered with jquery. Since I have put this step in, my form does not pass the variable of the selected option. I expect it to just post but it doesn't. I have always had it loaded dynamically, so I didn't think that was the issue. I can't get it to work by passing it through the URL either.

Here is my code: 
search.php

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <option value="<?=$row['id']?>"> <? echo $row['name'] ?></option>

<?php }

<form method = "post" action="index.php?page=users&id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">

                            <p>

                                <select name="list-select" id="list-select">
                                     <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                                        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                                        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                                        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>

                                        <option value="CA">California</option>
                                        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                                        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                                        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                                 </select>

                     <?php       

                    echo '<select name="list-target" id="list-target">';

                    echo '</select>';

                             $installation_id =  $_POST['list-target'];


                     mysqli_close($con);
                        ?>
```

users.php:

```
$installation_id = $_POST['list-target'];
```

.js

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#list-select").change(function() {
       $("#list-target").load("index.php?page=search&svalue=" + $("#list-select").val());
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure short tags are set, since you're using `<?=` and `<?`. If they're not, change those to `<?php echo` and `<?php` respectively.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything, and `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: Ok did all those. Nothing too notable with the error reporting. A notice about variables that weren't defined. I stuck them in an ISSET, so got rid of notice. But I still have the issue. Why is the variable not passing in the POST?

Comment: There's nothing in between `echo '<select name="list-target" id="list-target">';` and `echo '</select>';`. You sure you didn't mean to use `$installation_id = $_POST['list-select'];`?

Comment: The <select name="list-target" id="list-target"> is loaded via the jquery piece. The while statement is what loads into the list-target. (although I still don't understand how it knows to load that). It works I just can't grab the variable.